# Meaning of the code in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot, wolfram-mathematica, post-increment

As am new to mathematica,
pls do help me what is happening in the code given in mathematica.
I want to write it in matlab.

```
Clear[t, k, w, fg, g];   
t = 0;     
k = 0;      
For[a = 1, a < 26, t = t1, t1 = t + 8];   
g = ((−1)^a+1)∗ Integrate[Exp[−i ∗ w ∗ z],{z,t,t1}]; k = k + g; a++);    
fg[w_] = Re[k ∗ Conjugate[k]];      
li = Plot[fg[w], {w, 0.1, 0.7}], PlotRange → All, Frame → True]       
want to know how the for loop is working here.?
```

actual problem is integrate the function with respect to limits for a set of w values and with the changing of limits again integrating with same set of w values and summing up those integrated values.
where the input for 'w' values are taken here?

Comment: this is not valid mathematica code.  There are so many errors its hard to guess what its supposed to do..

Comment: what do you think are the errors?if u have the software ,have you run it?

Comment: Mathematica questions should be asked at [Mathematica.StackExchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com). But @george is right – I don't know were you got that code, but it's full of basic syntax errors if it's Mathematica code.

Comment: Examples the `(` in front of `Integrate` is a syntax error. The `For` loop runs forever because `a` is never updated in the loop. Code looks like it was copied by someone who didn't know the significance of different types of brackets and parenthesis.

Comment: Being a crossover mathematica/matlab question Id argue this *is* the right place. FWIW..

Comment: after these two lines that is which line will get executed?,for[a=1,a<26,t=t1,t1=t+8];           g=((-1)^a+1)*Integrate[Exp[-I*w*z],{z,t,t1};k=k+g;a++);

Comment: @George "a" is never getting updated ,this means what? a++ will not increment after integration,a<26 right,hence till 25 wont it run?

Comment: As I don't have the software mathematica ,I couldnot run it.pls do tell what will be the output for this program?

Comment: mathematica documentation is online, even if you dont have the software  you easily see the mistakes yourself if you start reading it http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/For.html  . Your `For` loop is terminated by the `]`. No change to a in the loop. No point in running this since it obviously will hang right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess at what this should look like:

```
 Clear[w];
 t = 0; k = 0;
 For[a = 1, a < 26, a++,
       g = ((-1)^a + 1)  Integrate[Exp[ -I   w   z], {z, t, t + 8}];
       k += g;
       t += 8];
 fg[w_] = Re[k   Conjugate[k]];
 Plot[fg[w], {w, 0.1, 0.7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

in more mathematicaesque form:

```
Clear[w]
fg[w_] = Re[#   Conjugate[#]] &@ 
          Sum[ ((-1)^a + 1) 
            8 Integrate[Exp[-I   w   (z + a - 1)  8 ], {z, 0, 1}] ,
               {a, 25}];
 Plot[fg[w], {w, 0.1, 0.7}, PlotRange -> All]
```